# $_Session variables not accessible on the same page they are created

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, mysqli

My issue is that for some reason on the login.php page of my website, I initialize some $_Session Variables from my users table in the corresponding database, but while these variables seem to function properly on other pages I can't do anything with them immediately after initializing them, because they don't seem to exist. This is an issue because I would like to reference the variables I have defined to create other session variables for efficiency, and because I would like to use it for a welcome message like the simple example shown in my code. Here is the code in question:

```
if(isset($_POST['user_email']) && !empty($_POST['user_email']) AND isset($_POST['user_pass']) && !empty($_POST['user_pass']))
{
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['user_email']); // Set variable for the username
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, sha1($_POST['user_pass'])); // Set variable for the password and convert it to an sha1 hash.

    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT user_email, user_pass, user_active FROM users WHERE user_email='".$email."' AND user_pass='".$password."' AND user_active='1'") or die(mysqli_error($link)); 
    if(!$result)
    {
        //something went wrong, display the error
        echo 'Something went wrong while signing in. Please try again later.';
             //echo mysql_error(); //debugging purposes, uncomment when needed
    }
    else
    {
        //the query was successfully executed, there are 2 possibilities
        //1. the query returned data, the user can be signed in
        //2. the query returned an empty result set, the credentials were wrong      
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
        {
            echo 'You have supplied a wrong user/password combination. Please try again.';
        }
        else
        {
            //set the $_SESSION['signed_in'] variable to TRUE
            $_SESSION['signed_in'] = true;

            //we also put the user_id and user_name values in the $_SESSION, so we can use it at various pages
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $_SESSION['user_id']    = $row['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['user_uuid']  = $row['user_uuid'];
                $_SESSION['user_level'] = $row['user_level'];
                $_SESSION['user_rank'] = $row['user_level'];                  
            }

            echo 'Welcome, ' . $_SESSION['user_uuid'] . '. <br /><a href="index.php">Proceed to the forum overview</a>.';
        }
    }
}
```

I have session_start(); at the top of my connect.php which is included at the top of the signin.php doc.

The result of this code on this page is something like:

```
Welcome, .
Proceed to the forum overview.
```

However if I run it on a different page on the site it properly prints, i.e.:

```
Welcome, username.
Proceed to the forum overview
```

Thanks.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: Do you really need a `while` loop to set the `$_SESSION` variables? It's only a single user, correct?